# MySQL won't update with URL variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having troubles getting my code to work properly. If I type it into phpMyAdmin it works, but when I try it in the code, it doesn't update the database.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("SERVER","USER","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $con);

$sp=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['file']);

$query = "UPDATE TDB SET WEIGHT=100000 WHERE PATH='$sp'"; 

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You have your quesry in a string, but you never execute it. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: 1: what's the error? 2: what's the value of $_GET['file']?

Comment: If you want to learn PHP PDO (newer "way" of connecting to databases) go to http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html, its a great resource. I learned allot from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code snippet and see how you get on.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("SERVER","USER","PASSWORD");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $con);
    $sp=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['file']);
    $query = "UPDATE TDB SET WEIGHT=100000 WHERE PATH='$sp'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

I would recommend doing it this way as mysql is no longer supported by PHP.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if (!$mysqli) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
} else {
    $sp = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['file']);
    $query = "UPDATE TDB SET WEIGHT=100000 WHERE PATH='$sp'"; 
    $mysqli->query(query);
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not EXECUTING your query. You're just defining a string that happens to contain some SQL, e.g.

```
$sql = "blah blah blah";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); <--forgot this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("SERVER","USER","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $con);

$sp=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['file']);

$sql = "UPDATE TRACKDB SET WEIGHT=100000 WHERE PATH='$sp'"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);

?>
```